# How to install Spitfire Audio on Wine with DXVK on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, wine, vulkan, vst

I installed Spitfire Audio on Ubuntu 22.04 (using Wine) but all I have is a black window. If I play around with resizing it and moving it around, I can get misplaced/suplicated text (but a lot is missing). Another user got this same blank screen on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxaudio/comments/zs7gys/spitfire_audio_labs_broke_after_latest_update/ [Note 1]. This is my first time installing Spitfire Audio, so the "solution" to the post I linked won't work for me.

After looking into things a bit more, and given the errors I was receiving (some had to do with Vulkan), I realised that I may need to install DXVK. There are so many different sets of instructions out there, and I can't seem to get any to work.

I tried `sudo apt-get install dxvk`, I tried downloading it from Github, I tried to follow instructions online, but I am a noob and can't make heads or tails of it (it doesn't help that there are many *different and varying* instructions (I have to install it and set it up to work in Wine).

There used to be a shellscript to make it easier, but that is no longer a part of DXVK.

Any help would be appreciated (the main problem is getting Spitfire Audio to work, so I could be wrong about DXVK). If need be, I can add screenshots of the errors I got (I am pretty sure I took screenshots) and I can show you what Spitfire Audio looks like (it shouldn't look like this).

---

1: Sorry, I don't know how to insert inline links and the Markdown help page on Stackexchange is no help at all. I can only get reference-style links and bare URLs to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Spitfire Audio working again in **PlayOLinux**.

I went to **PlayOnLinux Configuration**, under **install components**, i selected the **DXVK_2_00**-Package and pressed install.

So it runs normally as before.

*I hope it helps in anyway

Thank you and thanks for you investigation.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not familiar with PlayOnLinux. Its name sounds like it is more orientated torwards games. I just looked it up though, and it uses Wine. I will look into it.

Comment: @Paul, thank you **so much!** I've been trying to get this working again (also in PlayOnLinux) for the past several days; I can confirm that this solved this issue for me, as well! (In case it's useful for anyone else reading here in the future, I had also installed "Microsoft Core Fonts", "tahoma" and "tahoma2" via the "install components" tab in PlayOnLinux -- doing so seemed to fix another, possibly unrelated error in the logs, but your solution above is what got everything actually working again!)

Comment: Thanks Paul, Playonlinux worked great.

Comment: I will add, though, that PlayOnLinux crashes a lot at first when trying to download. Don't try to download too much at once, or it will crash again. I downloaded most of LABs and it crashed, I tried to choose the install via HDD option, but it is buggy (check your hard drive first before redownloading). I have still marked your answer as the correct one, though, Paul.